Apache error logs of module "proxy_ajp" is not converting to JSON format
We have converted our Apache error logs to JSON format by defining the format in httpd.conf file
ErrorLogFormat "{"timestamp":"%{u}t", "ApacheModule": "%m", "level":"%l", "ApacheProcessId": "%P", "ApacheThreadId": "%T", "ApacheSourceFile":"%7F", "ErrorKind":"%E", "ClientIp":"%a", "ErrorMessage" : "%M"}"
After defining above format all the logs are printed in JSON format despite one proxy_ajp module error
[Tue Apr 16 06:06:20.902697 2024] [proxy_ajp:error] [pid 11056:tid 38644] (OS 10054)An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.  : AH01030: ajp_ilink_receive() can't receive header
Other logs of proxy_ajp module are also successfully converted to JSON.
We have changed the format and just kept ErrorLogFormat %M . still above mentioned log is not converting to any format
I believe this particular log has no effect of ErrorLogFormat defined in httpd.conf file
Please help me to convert this log to JSON
